# Spring-Cloud-Config-Server not fetching properties files when using Spring-boot 2.0.1 RELEASE and spring-cloud-version Finchley.M9

Tags: spring, git, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have created a config-server using spring-cloud-config and have given my git uri in the bootstrap.yml. The server works fine and clones the properties files from github from the specified branch when i give spring-boot-version as 2.1.2.RELEASE and spring-cloud-version as Greenwich.RELEASE.

But when i use 2.0.1.RELEASE and spring-cloud-version as Finchley.M9, the properties files are not cloned from git.

Is this because of the change in spring-boot-version or the spring-cloud-version? 
I need to use 2.0.1.RELEASE and Finchley.M9 as this the one used by my other services.

Comment: Take a look here [spring cloud releases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/spring-cloud-finchley-release-notes) Finchley M9 mostly supports 2.0.0 .M9 versions only. It could be due to version compatibility. Share the logs to comment further

Comment: @Barath running the config-server using mvn spring-boot:run and sending a GET request to http://localhost:8888/execution-service/test return 404 Not Found Error, also with message: cannot clone or checkout from github repo {url}.
But in the case of 2.1.2 and Greenwich.RELEASE, when i do the same, i am getting the properties file from github execution-service-test.properties.